# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error - Parse + Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am working on a project where I have to retrieve multiple elements from Parse's database. The code I am working on is the following:

```
//
//  TableViewControllerCompiti.swift
//  Secondo B
//
//  Created by Edoardo on 23/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 ERC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class TableViewControllerCompiti: UITableViewController {

var selfTable: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var MessageTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var Compiti: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var FotoCompiti: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var DataCompiti: UILabel!

var messagesArray: [String] = [String]()
var imagesArray: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
var dateArray: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func retrieveMessages() {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Compiti")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (remoteObjects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            for messageObject in remoteObjects! {

                let messageText: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Materia"] as? String
                let imageText: UIImage? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Image"] as? UIImage
                let date: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Data"] as? String

                if messageText != nil {

                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
                    self.imagesArray.append(imageText!)
                    self.dateArray.append(date!)

                }
            }

            self.MessageTable.reloadData()

        }
    }

    retrieveMessages()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    Compiti.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
    FotoCompiti.image = self.imagesArray[indexPath.row]
    DataCompiti.text = self.dateArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.messagesArray.count

    }

}
```

When I run the application, it displays `Thread1: EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subside=0x0)`
error. In the Log it displays `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

[image]

This is how the cell should look like

[image]

This is how the cell looks like in the simulator.

[image]

I've also tried to put in some info from Parse, but without success.

Comment: You should debug to see if your query returns 0 message in remoteObjects, or if the problem lies after that.

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: @PhillipMills `self.imageArray.append(imageText!)`

Comment: So, it seems that you are receiving an object with messageText but no imageText.

Comment: @PhillipMills any idea of how can I transform that text in an image?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Transform?  (You can test `if imageText != nil` before the append.)

Comment: Force-unwrapping an optional without checking if it's nil first is always a bad idea. Also, in the future, you should specify the line on which the crash occurs so we don't have to hunt or guess. You're doing it everywhere and it's bad practice that causes more work to debug than you saved by not doing it right in the first place.